# Deploying flutter apps to embedded systems

Tags: flutter, dart

As flutter 2.0 is in the stable version and it has come with a lot of new things, what i am interested in is deploying a flutter app to an embedded system like a fridge or an AC. Just like Toyota has a flutter app for its infotainment system. On what hardware these apps run on? And how it is deployed on these hardwares.

Comment: Mh, difficult to say that because "fridge" is too general, but Toyota is working on flutter to import this app inside the car. However, buy the Dart convention, you should be able to compile directly with your architecture target. I can not say more than this because I understand all this new stuff with flutter